# How to tell if an SQL date is still in the future (not a query, I already have the desired row)

Tags: sql, date, compare

I have a row from an SQL table, and one field is a DATE. (The value may be undefined, as DATE has no default value). How can I tell if this date, if it exists, is still in the future?

I searched for answers and found lots of ways to extract all records that pass this test, but I don't want to do that. I just want to check this one previously extracted record. Sorry for the newbie question!

```
$userQuery  = "SELECT * FROM  `passwords` WHERE `name` = '$name' LIMIT 1";
$userResult     = mysql_query($userQuery);    
$userRow        = mysql_fetch_assoc($userResult); 
$bestBeforeDate = $userRow['bestBeforeDate']; // field is in DATE format
// what now? How to find if the 'best Before Date' has passed?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it in SQL as additional column

```
select case when (current_timestamp < date_column) 
            then 1
            else 0
            end as is_in_future
from your_table
```

### EDIT

You can do this in one query while reading other values from your table.
Example (not knowing the column names of your table)

```
select id,
       date_column,
       other_column,
       case when (current_timestamp < date_column) 
            then 1
            else 0
       end as is_in_future
from your_table
where some_conditions
```

Example output:

```
id  date_column   other_column   is_in_future
 1  2012-01-01    abc            0
 2  2012-08-01    def            1
 ...
```

Comment: Does this select from the original table? There are many records that fulfil that query, but I just want to check the record I have already extracted.

Comment: @ChrisTolworthy: You can add that to your query where you extract the `bestBeforeDate` from your database.

Comment: Thanks. I need also to read other variables from that record, regardless of whether it passes the date test. It sounds like I need to just make two different queries? I.e. query the table once to get the record AND check its date, and query the table again to get the same record regardless of the date?